# Can Sublime color Python docstrings differently from single-line strings?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, docstring

I'd like to differentiate between Python docstrings and single-line strings in Sublime Text 2.  Looking at the Python language definition, I can see this, along with a matching definition for apostrophe-strings that uses the same comment.block.python name.

```
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>^\s*(?=[uU]?[rR]?""")</string>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>(?&lt;=""")</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>comment.block.python</string>
...
```

But when I create a new color rule like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Docstring</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment.block.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#008800</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Nothing happens; they remain colored the same as single-line strings.

Is it possible to do this?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe change to:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Docstring</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string.quoted.double.block.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#008800</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I only tested it briefly, but it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Python.tmLanguage` has a little bug in it. Here's the fix for docstrings, although i am not sure if it's a nice one:

- replace the docstrings key with:

  ```
  <key>docstrings</key>
  <dict>
      <key>patterns</key>
      <array>
          <dict>
              <key>begin</key>
              <string>^\s*([uU]?[rR]?""")</string>
              <key>end</key>
              <string>(""")</string>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>comment.block.python</string>
          </dict>
          <dict>
              <key>begin</key>
              <string>^\s*(?=[uU]?[rR]?''')</string>
              <key>end</key>
              <string>(?&lt;=''')</string>
              <key>name</key>
              <string>comment.block.python</string>
          </dict>
      </array>
  </dict>
  ```
- add a single dict to as a first array of `string_quoted_double` and `string_quoted_single`

  ```
  <key>string_quoted_double</key>
  <dict>
      <key>patterns</key>
      <array>
          <dict>
              <key>include</key>
              <string>#docstrings</string>
          </dict>
  ```

This should automatically make docstrings become comments.